# Command Line Compiler stops working in specific project

Tags: c#, .net, csc, crash

I got this strange error saying that the 'Command Line Compiler has stopped working' when I try to build the solution.
The solution is 2 projects and a web MVC 4 Application.

As I have no idea what it is, I'll depend on your inputs to know what information to share about the solution.

Important: Any other projects I build dont show this error.

Error Details (in portuguese):

**FIRST ERROR:**

```
Assinatura do problema:
Nome do Evento de Problema: APPCRASH
Assinatura do Problema 01:  Csc.exe
Assinatura do Problema 02:  4.0.30319.17929
Assinatura do Problema 03:  4ffa73cb
Assinatura do Problema 04:  unknown
Assinatura do Problema 05:  0.0.0.0
Assinatura do Problema 06:  00000000
Assinatura do Problema 07:  c0000005
Assinatura do Problema 08:  0040e65c
Versão do sistema operacional:  6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.3
Identificação da Localidade:    1046
```

**SECOND ERROR:**

```
Nome do Evento de Problema: BEX
Nome do Aplicativo: Csc.exe
Versão do Aplicativo:   4.0.30319.17929
Carimbo de Data/Hora do Aplicativo: 4ffa73cb
Nome do Módulo de Falhas:   StackHash_0a9e
Versão do Módulo de Falhas: 0.0.0.0
Carimbo de Data/Hora do Módulo de Falhas:   00000000
Deslocamento de Exceção:    035aa4a8
Código de Exceção:  c0000005
Dados de Exceção:   00000008
Versão do sistema operacional:  6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.3
Identificação da Localidade:    1046
Informações Adicionais 1:   0a9e
Informações Adicionais 2:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
Informações Adicionais 3:   0a9e
Informações Adicionais 4:   0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

**THIRD ERROR:**

```
Nome do Evento de Problema: BEX
Nome do Aplicativo: Csc.exe
Versão do Aplicativo:   4.0.30319.17929
Carimbo de Data/Hora do Aplicativo: 4ffa73cb
Nome do Módulo de Falhas:   StackHash_211f
Versão do Módulo de Falhas: 0.0.0.0
Carimbo de Data/Hora do Módulo de Falhas:   00000000
Deslocamento de Exceção:    035aa4a8
Código de Exceção:  c0000005
Dados de Exceção:   00000008
Versão do sistema operacional:  6.1.7601.2.1.0.768.3
Identificação da Localidade:    1046
Informações Adicionais 1:   211f
Informações Adicionais 2:   211fe4273f7d301f2d472452323c0377
Informações Adicionais 3:   965e
Informações Adicionais 4:   965efd138aecdbb58a0c4ea5c1d2afe8
```

Visual Studio's Error List:

```
"Csc.exe" exited with code -1073741819.
```

**UPDATE:**

After repairing it didnt work, I unloaded the mvc4 project, created another empty mvc4 project, set it as Startup Project and it built correctly.

**UPDATE 2:**

I created a new mvc4 web project and switched with the problematic project. I added all the code files and it built successfuly.

*The question, however, remains unanswered.*

Thanks.

Comment: im repairing it... may take a while

Comment: repairing DID NOT WORK!

Comment: I have the same problem also just in one project, i have added a bounty hopeing for some decent answers.

Comment: Author is this still a problem a month down the line? How did you resolve this issue?

Comment: This error appeared after i try ed to publish my project to a file system.

Comment: bounty is on an answer, not the question.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and it came down to a malware file onto my computer stopping the Visual C# line compiler.

My problem file was bitguard.dll.

Adw Cleaner is a free malware cleaner that helped me find bitguard and remove it safely. http://download.cnet.com/AdwCleaner/3000-7786_4-75851221.html

Comment: ran adwcleaner 3 times, always different results, no changes at all!

Comment: also, there was no bitguard.dll among the results

Answer (score 0):

Try uninstall & reinstall Visual Studio.

Comment: yeah im looking for less drastic measures at this point but thanks

Answer (score 0):

just re-install the .net framework ;)

ps: boa sorte :)

Comment: I was thinking that if the problem was with the .net framework this error would show at every project I build, wouldnt it? valeu :)

Answer (score 0):

Run following command in the command prompt or run textbox devenv /resetuserdata. This fixed the issue in my case.