# Visual C# Command Line Compiler has stopped working?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, crash

I have a project iv been working on for sometime, but today when i tried to build the solution the following message was displayed.

[image]

This message appears twice when i try run my project, but the project is able to run after this appears.

The problem is i cant publish as this stops my publishing.

The problem signature reads the following:

```
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH 
Application Name: csc.exe 
Application Version: 4.0.30319.17929 
Application Timestamp: 4ffa73cb 
Fault Module Name: bitguard.dll 
Fault Module Version: 2.6.1694.246 
Fault Module Timestamp: 524a99fc 
Exception Code: c0000005 Exception 
Offset: 0017966f 
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.1 Locale ID: 7177 
Additional Information 1: 0a9e 
Additional Information 2: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789 
Additional Information 3: 0a9e 
Additional Information 4: 0a9e372d3b4ad19135b953a78882e789
```

I have run and build this project many times as well as publish, but this now has become a problem out of the blue.

This is only happening with one project and my other run and build fine.

I have posted a bounty on a similar question as i need this resolved quickly:

[Command Line Compiler stops working in specific project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18620040/1356321)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have a virus/malware problem -- look at the faulting module name (`bitguard.dll`) - see here: http://www.spywareremove.com/file/bitguarddll-367251/

Comment: Yes, bitguard appears to be a virus.

Comment: same situation here. Installed Malwarebytes and killed this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution with the help of Joe's comment above.

Following the Fault Module name you can see the problem file is bitguard.dll.
http://www.spywareremove.com/file/bitguarddll-367251/

Adw Cleaner is a free malware cleaner that helped me find bitguard and remove it safely.
http://download.cnet.com/AdwCleaner/3000-7786_4-75851221.html

The problem has been solved.

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion solve my problem http://download.cnet.com/AdwCleaner/3000-7786_4-75851221.html